# Error while executing webdriver-manager update

Tags: protractor, angular-cli, webdriver-manager

I followed the instruction of how to install protractor. While executing **webdriver-manager update**, i am getting this kind of issue.

```
events.js:183
throw er; // Unhandled  'error' event
Error: read ECONRESET
at _ernoException<util.js:1022:11>
at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:628:25)
```

I am behind a corporate proxy. Can somebody help on this?

Comment: Why downvoted my question?...it is legitimate question after all...

Comment: If you look up ECONRESET and node... "ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer): A connection was forcibly closed by a peer. This normally results from a loss of the connection on the remote socket due to a timeout or reboot. Commonly encountered via the http and net modules." This sounds like your environment has issues, probably the internet connectivity failed and you should retry. See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html

Comment: The internet is ok...but whenever i execute this command...i get this error...is there any other insight ?

Comment: Are you behind a corp firewall / proxy?

Comment: Yes... i am behind a corporate firewall

Comment: I have tried to get proxy for gecko to work but that definitely does not work nor do I have a fix for it. You could use a proxy but make sure you pass the --gecko false flag.

Comment: @cnishina it was written in the question

Answer (score 1):

If your network behind proxy, you need to tell `webdriver-manager` your proxy.

**Option 1)** Specify proxy in webdriver-manager CLI

```
webdriver-manager update --proxy <your proxy>
```

In this way, you have to specify proxy every time when execute `webdrvier-manager` start or update

**Option 2)** Add proxy setting in Environment Variable

```
HTTP_PROXY=<your proxy> 
HTTPS_PROXY=<your proxy> 
NO_PROXY=localhost, 127.0.0.1, .yourcompany.com
```

By this approach, no need to specify proxy in webdriver-manager CLI. However retry in new CMD window opened after adding proxy Environment Variables.

Comment: can you please elaborate option 1..?...Lets say, i want to execute e2e test on 4500 port..then what should be my executable command :
**webdriver-manager update --proxy 4500**

Comment: Hello Arka, please clarify your question, from your error I learn the issue failed to download webdriver binary due to network access.  It's nothing  matter with which port your e2e test run on.  From my view point,  you wan to execute e2e test on 4500 port means your app under test start on 4500 port, this port is no matter with your network proxy address port.  And `webdriver-manager update` can't control the port your app start on.

Comment: Please add information regards to 1)your app home page url,  2) your network proxy if you need it to access internet. If your issue occur in your company, you can contact with IT department to ask the proxy address, if occur in your home, generally we no need proxy to access network.

Comment: i am at the very beginning level of learning node. While installing protractor, i came accross this step. I am just worried, whether the failure of this statement execution may lead to some other discrepancy, which i cannot handle